# How to store users data like docs, audio, video in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

i want to make angular project where i want data like docs, audio, video to upload by the registered users and want to store and display on my home page. is it possible to store docs audio video if yes then how without using any server side script??

Answer (score 0):

Well, away from angularjs, you can use indexed DB in the modern browsers (assuming you're not using internet explorer) i don't know if there's any angularjs library for that, but on the indexed DB it self you will find a tutorial on how to use it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) and a good code examples [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store docs, audio, video permanently and reuse (show, download) them later then you must use any server side script to upload them.

angularJS is not able to upload any file to server directly.